# How to calculate sum of unique ways found in a distance matrx

Tags: r, geospatial

I have a data frame of 3 points in space represented by their longitude and latitute:

```
myData <- structure(list(lng = c(-37.06852042, -37.07473406, -37.07683313
), lat = c(-11.01471746, -11.02468103, -11.02806217)), .Names = c("lng", 
                                                                  "lat"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Next, I use the `geosphere` package to get a distance matrix (in meters, which I convert to km) for the points:

```
> m <- round(distm(myData)/1000,2)
> rownames(m) <- c("A", "B", "C")
> colnames(m) <- c("A", "B", "C")
> m
     A    B    C
A 0.00 1.30 1.74
B 1.30 0.00 0.44
C 1.74 0.44 0.00
```

Given this is a distance matrix and I have 6 ways of going to A, B and C (like A -> B -> C, C -> A >-B, and so on), I would like to extract some information from it, like the minimum, the median, and the maximum distance.

To illustrate it, I calculated all the possible ways of my example manually:

```
ways <- c(abc <- 1.3 + 0.44,
             acb <- 1.74 + 0.44,
             bac <- 1.3 + 1.74,
             bca <- 0.44 + 1.74,
             cab <- 1.74 + 1.3,
             cba <- 0.44 + 1.3)
> min(ways)
[1] 1.74
> median(ways)
[1] 2.18
> max(ways)
[1] 3.04
```

How do I automate this task, given that I'll be working with more than 10 locals and this problem has factorial complexity?

Comment: So your question is how to automate the rownames and colnames to get values A-Z or more if there are more lats and longs? OR will there always be three points only? A,B & C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a package called [trotter](https://github.com/ram6ler/trotter) that maps integers to different arrangement types (permutations, combinations and others). For this problem, it seems that you are interested in the permutations of locations. One of the objects in the package is the *permutation pseudo-vector* that is created using the function `ppv`.

First install "trotter":

```
install.packages("trotter")
```

Then an automated version of your task might look something like:

```
library(geosphere)
myData <- data.frame(
  lng = c(-37.06852042, -37.07473406, -37.07683313), 
  lat = c(-11.01471746, -11.02468103, -11.02806217)
)

m <- round(distm(myData) / 1000, 2)

locations <- c("A", "B", "C")
rownames(m) <- colnames(m) <- locations

library(trotter)

perms <- ppv(k = length(locations), items = locations)
ways <- c()

for (i in 1:length(perms)) {
  perm <- perms[i]
  route <- paste(perm, collapse = "")
  ways[[route]] <- sum(
    sapply(
      1:(length(perm) - 1),
      function(i) m[perm[i], perm[i + 1]]
    )
  )
}
```

Back in the R console:

```
> ways
 ABC  ACB  CAB  CBA  BCA  BAC 
1.74 2.18 3.04 1.74 2.18 3.04 
> # What is the minimum route length?
> min(ways)
[1] 1.74
> # Which route (index) is this?
> which.min((ways))
ABC 
  1
```

Just remember, like you said, you're dealing with factorial complexity and you might end up waiting a while running this brute force search with more than a few locations...

Comment: It does indeed work, unfortunately my problem is too complex to run when N > 10. Anyway, thanks for the heads up, your package seems to be really cool.

Comment: Nice idea in `ppv` to generate permutations when needed. Also, you could pre-allocate "ways" as a "list" of `length(perms)` and -exchange some memory for speed- by using something like `ways[[i]] = setNames(sum(m[cbind(perm[-length(perm)], perm[-1L])]), paste(perm, collapse = ""))` instead of the `sapply`.